# Do leshies need to sleep?

Tags: races, pathfinder-2e

Pathfinder 2e introduced leshies, spirits inhabiting plant-based host bodies, as a player race, found here in the SRD: https://2e.aonprd.com/Ancestries.aspx?ID=14

Our group has been having a discussion on whether leshies need to sleep or not.

The arguments from one side are that as the leshy is plant-based, and plants do not need sleep, the leshy also does not need sleep.

The other side suggests that since it's not explicitly stated anywhere, that leshies do need to sleep as other ancestries- the only ancestry (as far as we can see) that mentions sleep in the entry is the android, which says

> Androids breathe, eat, and sleep like a human, although they're incapable of biological procreation.

The closest the leshy entry comes to that would be, under 'Plant Nourishment':

> You gain nourishment in the same way that the plants or fungi that match your body type normally do, through some combination of photosynthesis, absorbing minerals with your roots, or scavenging decaying matter.

Which doesn't explicitly mention sleep, though the interpretation could potentially be stretched to include 'sleeping in the same way that the plants or fungi that match your body type normally do' - i.e. not at all.

Since leshies do not have an inherent resistance to magical sleep effects, they are clearly capable of sleep, however that doesn't necessarily mean they need to in the same way the humans need their 8 hours nightly.

Comment: There might be an answer in a lore source somewhere as to what "Leshy Sleep" looks like, but I am unaware of any and unable to find any.

Comment: Are we sure plants don't sleep most of the time?

Comment: @Ifusaso a quick google shows that plants *actually* sleep, in a way. That may be a question for another Stack Exchange site... but apparently they take a break from photosynthesis and other stuff based upon a circadian rhythm. Does that constitute a frame challenge answer? lol (see https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61329/do-plants-need-sleep)

Answer (score 6):

## RAW: they need to rest somehow

First, regardless of whether or not a leshy needs sleep for biological reasons, mechanically they are required to rest.

From Core Rulebook page 480:

> Once every 24 hours, you can take a period of rest (typically 8 hours) [...]. If you go more than 16 hours without resting, you become fatigued [...].

There is nothing in leshy-specific rules that overrules that.

As for the concern or whether or not leshies should engage in some kind of sleep during this rest (this could be important because a creature is typically uncounscious during sleep), I would let the player of the character decide of the flavor (sleep, shut down, stasis, meditation) and have the GM rule on how it impacts the character perception during the rest period.

Comment: The rules on [Resting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=534) are available in more detail on p499

Comment: Also notable, there is no text anywhere that [Plant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=125) creatures don't sleep or are immune. Specifically, none of the [Leshy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=225) monsters have immunity to sleep. I see no indication that not sleeping was carried over from 1e yet